# Organise project structure

Tags: rust, namespaces

I'm working on extending a Rust project. Coming from the C++ world, I'm looking for a `namespace`-like concept.

The file structure of the Rust project looks like that:

```
src
|
|--lib.rs
|
|--examples/example.rs
|
|--level1
|     |---verify.rs // pub fn verify(...)
|     |---keygen.rs // pub fn gen_key(...)
|     |---sign.rs   // pub fn sign(...)
|     |---mod.rs    // pub mod verify; pub mod keygen; pub mod sign; 
|
|--level2
|     |---verify.rs // pub fn verify(...)
|     |---keygen.rs // pub fn gen_key(...)
|     |---sign.rs   // pub fn sign(...)
|     |---mod.rs    // pub mod verify; pub mod keygen; pub mod sign;
```

I think that, acc. to Rust terminology, I have one crate and several modules with the same name (e.g. two modules called `sign`, derived from the filenames `sign.rs`).

I can access e.g. the `sign()` function of `level1` from the implementation of `level2 / sign.rs / sign()` in a concise but unambiguous way:

level2/sign.rs:

```
use crate::level1;

pub fn sign() {
  level1::sign();
}
```

Afaik, the whole API for any user (as well as for `example1.rs`) is provided via `lib.rs` and each folder's `mod.rs`. Now I can use e.g.

examples/example1.rs:

```
use crate_name::*;
fn main() {
  crate_name::level1::sign::sign();
  crate_name::level2::sign::sign();
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to achieve the following (leave out the filename/module name), and if yes: how?

```
[...]
fn main() {
  crate_name::level1::sign();
  crate_name::level2::sign();
}
```

2. The files like `level1/sign.rs` are called `modules` (`sign`). What are the folders like `level1` called? They are neither crates or modules -- is there a terminology?
3. I see that files like `level1/sign.rs` are considered as `modules`, because the `mod.rs` contains a statement like `pub mod sign` without any declaration `mod sign { ... }`. So I assume there's a convention to, as default, have a module called like the source file. And other modules in the same file can be introduced via `mod tests { ... }`. Do I understand that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve the following (leave out the filename/module name)?

If you have created modules that are not meaningful subdivisions in your crate's public API, you can and should hide them via **reexports**. Your `level1/mod.rs` presumably currently contains:

```rust
pub mod verify;
pub mod keygen;
pub mod sign;
```

It should instead contain the following. (Note that the modules themselves are no longer public.)

```rust
mod verify;
pub use verify::verify;
mod keygen;
pub use keygen::keygen;
mod sign;
pub use sign::sign;
```

Or you may use glob imports to reexport everything public from every module:

```rust
mod verify;
pub use verify::*;
mod keygen;
pub use keygen::*;
mod sign;
pub use sign::*;
```

When designing your public modules, I strongly recommend you run `cargo doc --open` and look at the produced **documentation for your library**, and think about whether the organization (and the documentation text accompanying it) will be clear to your users.

> The files like `level1/sign.rs` are called modules (`sign`). What are the folders like `level1` called? They are neither crates or modules -- is there a terminology?

It's just the folder where the code for child modules of the `level1` module are looked for by the compiler. It is not itself any kind of element of a Rust program.

Note also that `src/level1/mod.rs` is the source file for the module named `level1`. (You can also place it at `src/level1.rs` instead; this style is newer, and weakly recommended over the older style, but taste varies and there's no harm in using `mod.rs`.)

> I see that files like `level1/sign.rs` are considered as `modules`, because the `mod.rs` contains a statement like `pub mod sign` without any declaration `mod sign { ... }`. So I assume there's a convention to, as default, have a module called like the source file. And other modules in the same file can be introduced via `mod tests { ... }`. Do I understand that correctly?

I would say, rather, that `src/level1/sign.rs` is *not* a module, it's a source code file; modules are [**items**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items.html) that, like other items such as functions and types, are **declared in source code** (`mod sign;` or `mod sign {...}`). The file layout on disk is just where the compiler automatically looks for code files based on your module declarations, and has no more significance to the program than (usually) having a distinct path for each module you declare.

Think about your `mod`s as being the fundamental organization of your crate, and source file layout as a convention for how to store the code for the `mod`s in a predictable location. (It's [possible](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute) to direct the compiler to look for a module's source code in a different location — but don't do that, because it confuses readers, and situations where it looks like that is a good option are usually better handled other ways.)

Comment: Thanks -- I've tried the approach from your answer with a minimal example. I had to add `pub mod level1;` etc. in `lib.rs` to get exactly what I wanted. So it seems that the `lib.rs` can access what's provided in the respective `mod.rs` files, and the API is in `lib.rs`. Reg. "modules": So if I have a file `./level1/sign.rs`, there is no module `sign` as long as I don't declare it as `mod sign` in `mod.rs`. If I do that, then a filename convention applies, i.e. I don't need to declare `mod sign` n `sign.rs`.

Comment: @radix That all sounds right. Regarding "the `lib.rs` can access…" — you might want to read about [visibility and privacy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html), or post another question if you're still wondering.